# How to upload data to cumulocity using RPi?

Tags: raspberry-pi, cumulocity

I have connected a RPi to Cumulocity and I would like to know how I can upload data from the RPi. I suppose I can write a python code that does that?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "connected a RPi to Cumulocity"? Did you use the java-agent or write your own python agent?

Comment: By connected to Cumulocity I mean registered the device on the platform using the serial num. The next step I believe would be to write a code that would collect the data and send it to the platform, is this correct? and if so how is it done?

Answer (score 0):

The source code of the software that "connects" the raspberry pi to Cumulocity is available [here](https://bitbucket.org/m2m/cumulocity-examples/src/d91ea3ab772054a22acd07f7656128915d291bca/java-agent/?at=default). In order to add extra functionality you will have to extend it. However it is java not python.